# Spring Security in Grails to handle XSS JSESSIONID

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, xss

Environment settings;
Grails 2.3.9
Spring Security spring-security-core:1.2.7.3

Issue is around XSS and how JSESSIONID is being created and destroyed. In my config.groovy session fixation is set to true;

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSessionFixationPrevention = true
```

More information available at [Session Fixation Prevention](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/sessionFixation.html)

My understanding is that a JSESIONID is created upon hitting the landing page, after logging in successfully a new JSESIONID is created. When the user logs out the loggedin JSESIONID is destroyed and a new one is created. Im unable to confirm what happens to the first JSESIONID? Is this destroyed? What is the best practice here i.e. should the first JSESIONID be manually destroyed when the user has loggedin, like so;

```
//force to create a new session, to avoid hacked session id
 try {
     request.getSession(false).invalidate();
     request.getSession()

  } catch (Exception e) {
     log.warn("Error invalidating session")
  }
```

This issue came up as part of a security scan and a recommended fix was to destroy the first JSESSIONID. Surely Spring Security has thought about this issue!  Is there any best practice or recommended configuration to handle this scenario. Would rather use spring security configuration than creating custom code.

Any help is appreciated.

J

Comment: the flag is supposed to exaclty this: create a new session after a successful login.  have you tried/verified it in your installation?  did your auditor gave you any evidence (e.g. some burp report)?

Comment: The title of the issue is 'Session Not Invalidated After Logout'. Just looking to confirm that Spring security is doing its job as the recommended fix is to invalidate relevant session identifiers when a user signs out.

Comment: Spring Security does not invalidate the first JSESSIONID which is now orphaned as a new one is created when a user logs in. I dont see this being a security problem though? I only care about the second JSESSIONID being cleaned up correctly.